# I need to be able to sort time column in r (but it's a collection of hours, days, weeks spent, not time in its normal format)

Tags: r

I have a chr column that contains time spent on a request in the following format -> 1mos 3w 1d 0h 0m 0s. When I am trying to sort the column and arrange the content in the desc order, it does not work (of course), as the order is based on numerics:

[image]

How could I convert this into time column (or smth) to be able to sort it correctly (with 6 months bigger then 7 days? Thank you in advance.
I am out of ideas...

Comment: Could you provide an example of how your data looks like? please take a look at this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Use a regex. `hours <- as.numeric(stringr::str_match(mydata$column, "(\\d+)h")[,2])`. Similarly for the other numbers. Then you can just do `time <- hours * 3600 + mins * 60 + secs` etc.